# Merge Rows (diff) is comparing row by row, not one row to entire rows of other table

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am comparing two sheets using Merge Rows (diff).

1st excel sheet:

[image]

2nd excel sheet:

[image]

and my pentaho transaction:

[image]

in preview data showing, that id 2.0 at 2nd row is add new row and at 4 row its showing same data is delete, its suppose to identical, so how it can be achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merge rows (diff) requires both input streams to be sorted by the merge keys (there's a warning about it when you edit the step's properties).

Put a sort rows step in each stream ahead of the Merge Rows (diff) step.

Comment: Upvoted @nsouza answer. And don't be afraid of time performance or memory issues. The PDI is quite clever.